# Solution: Iterator which doesn't know if it has a next element

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, iterator, software-design

I wrote an iterator, which returns subgraphs of a fixed size of another given undirected simple graph. 
It maintains an internal graph which is the currently calculated subgraph and has private stacks and lists from which it calculates the next subgraph.

It is not possible to know if the iterator can return another element, because maybe the algorithm terminates when trying to find the next subgraph.

In this design, the pattern of `next()` and `hasNext()` which Java offers doesn't work out. I currently wrote my own Interface *BlindIterator* with the following abstract methods:

```
 /**
 * @return True iff the current element is a valid return.
 */
public boolean hasCurrent();

/**
 * @return Returns the current element, but does NOT generate the next element. This method can be called


 * as often as wanted, without any side-effects.
 */
public T getCurrent();

/**Generates the next element, which can then be retrieved with getCurrent(). This method thus only provides
 * this side-effect. If it is called while the current element is invalid, it may produce and exception,
 * depending on the implementation on the iterator.
 */
public void generateNext();
```

Is this a common pattern and are there better designs than mine?

Comment: So then how would you proceed to the next node, if #getCurrent returns the current node. I think an iterator would work fine here, you can use #hasNext to determine if a next valid node exists, your current node would _always_ be valid, and #next would be a blocking/expensive call. You can then optimize your code around #next and avoid expensive generation with #hasNext

Comment: How do *safely* start the iteration and get the first element? If generateNext *"is called while the current element is invalid, it may produce and exception"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you have created is equivalent to the `Iterator` interface. Here is an implementation of `Iterator` using your `BlindIterator`:

```
    class BlindIteratorIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

        private BlindIterator<T> iterator;

        public BlindIteratorIterator(BlindIterator<T> iterator) {
            this.iterator = iterator;
            iterator.generateNext();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iterator.hasCurrent();
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            T next = iterator.getCurrent();
            iterator.generateNext();
            return next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `next()` must throw `NoSuchElementException` if `hasNext()` would return `false`. The question doesn't specify what `getCurrent()` does when there is no current value, so the iterator implementation shouldn't rely on that. E.g. `getCurrent()` could return `null` or throw `IllegalStateException`, neither of which would be valid for `next()`.

Comment: This answer solves the problem that I stated, but I realized that I don't really capture what I was struggling with. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961357/java-iterator-is-supposed-to-always-return-the-same-object-but-should-change-i) is my new question.

Answer (score 1):

You implement the iterator to preload/cache the next element (subgraph).

For example, if your elements are sourced from a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), where the only method is a [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html#get--) method that returns the next element, or `null` if no more elements are available, you would implement the [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) like this:

```
public final class SupplierIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

    private final Supplier<E> supplier;
    private E next;

    SupplierIterator(Supplier<E> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
        this.next = supplier.get(); // cache first (preload)
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (this.next != null);
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        if (this.next == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        E elem = this.next;
        this.next = supplier.get(); // cache next
        return elem;
    }
}
```

---

[Answer by Joni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60960517/5221149) has a good `Iterator` implementation that can use your intended `BlindIterator` as the source of elements.

Since you only invented the `BlindIterator` to work around your perceived limitations of `Iterator`, I'd recommend not doing that. Make the iterator implementation call the underlying "generate" logic directly.